# Consulta especifica en Firebase con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase

Estoy tratando de integrar firebase con mi proyecto python. Utiliando firebase cloud.

Quiero obtener un resultado como el siguiente:

> Nombre: xxxxx 
> Apellido: xxxxxxx
>  Direcion: xxxxxxx

Para ello utilize el siguiente código para realizar la consulta.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/nuevo.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

carpeta = db.collection(u'Usuarios')
nombre1 = carpeta.get()

for n in nombre1:
    print(u'{}:{}'.format(n.id,n.to_dict()))
```

Pero el resultado que me arroja es:

```
Adminstradores:{'Dirección': 'Zaragoza 17', 'Nombre': 'Angel', 'Apelliso': 'Alvarez'}
[Finished in 2.6s]
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

esta es la estructura de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es asignar a otra variable el valor del diccionario `s = d.to_dict()`

Dando un resultado asi:

```
for d in data:
   s = d.to_dict()
   print('Nombre: {} \n Apellido: {} \n Dirección: {}\n'.format(s['Nombre'],s['Apelliso'],s['Dirección']))
```

Se mostaran todos los datos:

```
 Nombre: Angel 
 Apellido: Alvarez 
 Dirección: Zaragoza 17

 Nombre: jose 
 Apellido: alvarez 
 Dirección: Victoria #4

[Finished in 2.8s]
```